# missing value true / false: error in loop not in one-off

Tags: r, testing, date, if-statement, boolean

I am new on R and I have a problem with a test in a loop that I want to code. With a data frame (tabetest) like the one here after:

```
    Date    25179M103
1   14977   77.7309
2   14978   77.2567
3   14979   77.7507
```

I have:

```
> if (tabetest[3,"Date"] - tabetest[1,"Date"] > 1){ print("ok") }

[1] "ok"
```

But:

```
j = 1 
position = 1
price = tabetest

for (i in 1:nrow(tabetest) - position){
   if (tabetest[i + position,"Date"] - tabetest[position,"Date"] > 20{
       price[i + position,j] = price[i + position,j] / price[position,j] - 1}
       position = position + 1
   }
```

Returns an error. R says that there is a missing value where true/false is required in:

```
 if (tabetest[i + position, "Date"] - tabetest[position, "Date"] >
```

I have spent quite some time on that error but still don't understand where it comes from.

Answer (score 4):

First, you have an order of operations problem.  You need to put parentheses around `nrow(tabetest)-position`

The following is the same as `c(1, 2, 3) - 1`

```
> 1:3-1
[1] 0 1 2
```

But, this is the same as `c(1, 2)`

```
> 1:(3-1)
[1] 1 2
```

However, after you fix that you'll still have a problem.  The second time through the loop, `i` is 2 and `position` is 2.  That means that `tabetest[i + position, "Date"]` is `NA` because `position + i == 4`, but there are only 3 rows the `data.frame`.

This is mostly a guess, but maybe you want to only increment `position` if the condition in the `if` statement is `TRUE` like this:

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(tabetest)-position)){
    if(tabetest[i+position,"Date"]-tabetest[position,"Date"]>20){
        price[i+position,j]=price[i+position,j]/price[position,j]-1
        position=position+1
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If so, please check the checkmark next to the answer to "accept" it. Thanks.